# How do I reset primary key according to timestamp in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sorting, primary-key

I know that I can reset the primary key in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

But I'm wondering how I can adapt this to apply the primary key according to the timestamp in my timestamp column, i.e. the row with the oldest timestamp gets the value 1, the next oldest, the value 2, etc.

**OUTPUT of SHOW CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `from_user` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `source_filename` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `uploaded_page` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `operating_system` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `browser` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `os_browser_version` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `artist` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `album` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `genre` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 `format` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `bitrate` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `conversion_needed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'if not mp3, or higher than 192kbps',
 `conversion_successful` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `art_extracted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `art_location` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `file_location` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `status` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=96 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: For what reason? The exact value of primary key should never care you

Comment: I'd just like the primary key to be in sequence with the timestamp of my records

Comment: is there **real technical reason** behind that? Or you just woke up today and realized that you want that?

Comment: no, not a real technical reason.  The usual scheme of things is that the primary key with auto increment corresponds to the sequence of records added to a table.  I combined two tables and now I'd like the numbering to follow the timestamp

Comment: If it's not a technical reason - then just learn to live with it

Comment: well, if there's a way of doing it, why learn to live with it?

Comment: because it makes no sense. PK is an unique identifier. Its only requirement is to be unique. Nothing else. Being in sequence with some another column - is not what it was invented for.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I thought that the PK was what was used to set the default order (sorting) of the table, and I would like my table to always be sorted by timestamp.

Comment: generally tables don't have any order (actually they do, but it's not a thing you should rely ever) until you explicitly specify `ORDER BY` in your query

Comment: Why is your table suddenly called `tracks` instead of `users`?

Comment: @MarkByers Ah, yes, sorry.  I was using a generic example in my original question.  Table is actually called 'tracks'

Comment: For what it's worth I disagree with @zerkms. I think this is a perfectly reasonable question. It also has a very simple answer, which I provided below.

Comment: @Ike Walker: "simple" answer stops being simple when you have relations (or stored objects) to this table. Questions not driven by *real issue* aren't reasonable

Comment: @zerkms I agree that you should not change existing primary key values for a table with dependencies. But I disagree with your premise that one should never care about primary key values or try to dictate the order of a table's rows.

Comment: @Ike Walker: it is absolutely pointless step from DB design point of view. So - as long as it makes no sense - I personally don't see any reason to do it. And you should never rely on actual PK values, thus - it doesn't matter what actual value is there.

Comment: @zerkms: The physical order of the rows on disk affects performance, so therefore I think it's relevant.

Comment: @Ike Walker: yes, if the question were related to performance and optimization - it would be a perfect question. But the question based on "I just like it more" is not about performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new table called `users2` that has the same structure as `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE users2 LIKE users;
```

Then run this statment:

```
INSERT INTO users2
(col1, col2, ... coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln
FROM users
ORDER BY your_timestamp
```

For your specific table:

```
INSERT INTO tracks2
(`timestamp`,`from_user`,`source_filename`,`uploaded_page`,`operating_system`,`browser`,`os_browser_version`,`title`,`artist`,`album`,`genre`,`format`,`bitrate`,`conversion_needed`,`conversion_successful`,`art_extracted`,`art_location`,`file_location`,`status`)
SELECT `timestamp`,`from_user`,`source_filename`,`uploaded_page`,`operating_system`,`browser`,`os_browser_version`,`title`,`artist`,`album`,`genre`,`format`,`bitrate`,`conversion_needed`,`conversion_successful`,`art_extracted`,`art_location`,`file_location`,`status`
FROM tracks
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to specify all the columns for each table as I have a lot of columns?

Comment: @Nick: No. In particular you should *not* specify the `id` column. By the way, having a lot of columns is often a sign of bad database design.

Comment: It worth to mention that swapping tables back `users2 -> users` may be a tricky process

Comment: @MarkByers Thanks.  Well, I have 20 columns, perhaps that's not so many.  What would the statement look like for copying all the columns except the ID column, without having to type out the other 19?

Comment: @Nick: If you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` I can type the query for you. It's really not that much effort at all if you have a decent editor. Note that line 2 and 3 are the same, so once you have typed line 2 you can copy + paste it to get line 3.

Comment: @MarkByers Thanks. I've appended output to question.

Comment: There. It took about 2 minutes. I didn't have to type anything except pressing "delete".

Comment: @MarkByers Thanks again, I get the gist of it now.  Unfortunately I am getting an error though: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE tracks2 (`timestamp`,`from_user`,`source_filename`,`uploaded_page`,`operat' at line 1"

Comment: Oops, TABLE shouldn't have been there. By the way, if you have trouble with getting a query working, I highly recommend reading the manual page for the relevant statement (here you want the page for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)) and using that page to figure out what the correct syntax is.

Comment: @Mark Byers That works fine.  Thanks for the help and the education!

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but for the sake of posterity I want to chime in with a simpler solution. MySQL allows you to re-order the rows of a table using [`ALTER TABLE...ORDER BY...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html), so you can easily do this by adding one more `ALTER TABLE` statement to your original example:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` DROP COLUMN `id`;
ALTER TABLE `users` ORDER BY `timestamp`;
ALTER TABLE `users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Comment: +1 Because this solves the OP's main concern that he didn't want to have to type the column names.